# View is being initiated, but drawRect: is not called

Tags: objective-c, macos, view, drawrect

What I have is a blank application wherein I attempt to draw a view on the main window programmatically, that is to say without first dragging on a "Custom View" from Interface Builder. Judging from some breakpoints and some NSLogs() I set up, it seems that when I call

```
RectangleDrawer *rectangle1 = [[RectangleDrawer alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 50, 50)];
[[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView] addSubView:rectangle1];
```

I can tell that my rectangle1 is being initiated because it prints an NSLog but it does not draw the view on the window. That is to say the `-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect` is not being called, it doesn't print the NSLog within. The RectangleView is simple, a subclass of `NSView` it calls `NSRectFill([self bounds])` with `NSBlueColor`.

When I drag the view onto Interface Builder and set it's class to RectangleView it works perfectly... Draws a blue box like a charm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the bottom line to read

`[_window.contentView addSubview:rectangle1];`

and now it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

I see you adding the subview, but I don't see you telling anything to redraw.  What happens if you send `-setNeedsDisplay:YES` to the superview?

Comment: Nothing. Also when, in the initWithFrame: method I call [self display] nothing happens either.